# Haskell Mini Function Implementation

Tags: haskell

I have been trying to take this function and make small implementation using iterate and takeWhile. It doesn't have to be using those functions, really I'm just trying to turn it into one line. I can see the pattern in it, but I can't seem to exploit it without basically making the same code, just with iterate instead of recursion.

```
fun2 :: Integer -> Integer
fun2 1 = 0
fun2 n 
    | even n = n + fun2 (n `div` 2)
    | otherwise = fun2 (3 * n + 1)
```

Any help would be great. I've been struggling with this for hours.
Thanks

Comment: What's wrong with your 4 line version? I think it's perfectly clear and reads better than any 1 line version would.

Comment: Its just a challenge for a Haskell class. With the time I've spent on it I really just wanted some advice. I have a slightly slimmer version.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to do this with `iterate`, the key is to chop it up into smaller logical parts:

- generate a sequence using the rule

  a<sub>k+1</sub> = a<sub>k</sub>/2 if a<sub>k</sub> even

  a<sub>k+1</sub> = 3a<sub>k</sub>+1 if a<sub>k</sub> odd
- stop the sequence at a<sub>j</sub> = 1 (which all do, if the [collatz conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture) is true).
- filter out the even elements on the path
- sum them

So then this becomes:

```
  f = sum . filter even . takeWhile (>1) . iterate (\n -> if even n then n `div` 2 else 3*n + 1)
```

However, I do think this would be clearer with a helper function

```
  f = sum . filter even . takeWhile (>1) . iterate collatz
    where collatz n | even n    = n `div` 2
                    | otherwise = 3*n + 1
```

This may save you no lines, but transforms your recursion into the generation of data.

Comment: Yeah your if statement line was just what I was thinking but couldn't figure out how to implement. Helper function is awesome as well. Thanks man.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, I agree with tom's comment that there is nothing wrong with your four line version. It's perfectly readable. However, it's occasionally a fun exercise to turn Haskell functions into one liners. Who knows, you might learn something!

At the moment you have

```
fun 1 = 0
fun n | even n    = n + fun (n `div` 2)
      | otherwise = fun (3 * n + 1)
```

You can always convert an expression using guards into an `if`

```
fun 1 = 0
fun n = if even n then n + fun (n `div` 2) else fun (3 * n + 1)
```

You can always convert a series of pattern matches into a case expression:

```
fun n = case n of
            1 -> 0
            _ -> if even n then n + fun (n `div` 2) else fun (3 * n + 1)
```

And finally, you can convert a case expression into a chain of `if`s (actually, in general this would require an `Eq` instance for the argument of your function, but since you're using `Integer`s it doesn't matter).

```
fun n = if n == 1 then 0 else if even n then n + fun (n `div` 2) else fun (3 * n + 1)
```

I think you'll agree that this is far less readable than what you started out with.

Answer (score 0):

One liner ;)

```
fun2 n = if n==1 then 0 else if even n then n + fun2 (n `div` 2) else fun2 (3 * n + 1)
```

My sense is that short of look-up tables, this function cannot be implemented without recursion because the argument passed in the recursion seems unpredictable (except for n as powers of 2).

On the other hand, rampion helped me learn something new.